# Definition query to display only part of layer that overlaps with specific polygon using ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, export, definition-query

I have a very large roads data set and I would like to write a definition query that displays only the roads that are inside of a polygon. This would make my export to pdf a much smaller file size. I know I could clip them but I don't want to make a new dataset.

Also I could create layer from selection, but I am very curious if this possible with a definition query?

Answer (score 4):

You can find what you are looking for in Dataframe properties. (See screenshot)

1- Go to Dataframe properties

2- Dataframe tab

3- Choose (Clip to Shape)

4- In specify shape (Choose your polygon)

5- Exclude layer (You can exclude layer from clip if you want)

[image]

Comment: If you managed to select the features of interest, and you really want to use definition query, then you may simply create a new field to flag them out (fill selected features of interest with 1 and the rest with 0). now you can use definition query to show only those having value = 1

Comment: maybe he has no permission for changing the database structure, also the definition away does not crop the lines at intersection with polygon, another away is by clipping the feature and creating a new feature (the one that sparky mentioned in question). whatever if this solution is OK, please sparky mark it as solved